# Traveling salesman library using approximation algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, traveling-salesman, approximation

I'm currently doing a project that requires some fast TSP solving (about 50-100 nodes in 2 seconds). There are a lots of approximation algorithms out there, but I don't have time nor will to analyze them and code them myself.

Are there any free libraries that can solve TSP problem (approximation will do too)? Something like `sortedNodes = solveTspPrettyPlease(nodes, 2sec)` would be just great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 " *Something like sortedNodes = solveTspPrettyPlease(nodes, 2sec) would be just great* "   I lol'ed.  :)   If only everything could be solved like that.  Imagine this:  *pleaseRunMyEntireApplicationAsItShouldKThxBye()*.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- http://code.google.com/p/java-traveling-salesman/ - genetic algorithm solution
- http://www.adaptivebox.net/CILib/code/tspcodes_link.html - links to *many* solutions, not all of which (if any?) are libraries

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the http://code.google.com/p/java-traveling-salesman/ link, you'll need to get the CVS version of jgap from April 1, 2006.  You'll also need to hack the tsp code a little bit.  Change JGapGreedyCrossoverEngine.java from protected double evaluate(Chromosome a_subject)  to protected double evaluate(IChromosome a_subject)